# Expression MVC2

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use expression in Java MVC 
`<p>${i}</p>` 
I define a method

```
public static String test(int i) {
    //
}
```

I can't call method `test` in Expression
`${test(i)}` 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is to create a custom taglib and create a Expression Language.

So, you must define a tld in your WEB-INF folder (for example /WEB-INF/my-functions.tld)

This file is a xml and it look like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
   <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
   <uri>http://www.your-domain.com/taglib</uri>
   <short-name>my-functions</short-name>
   <description>Whatever</description>
   <function>
       <name>writeHello</name>
       <function-class>your.package.YourClass</function-class>
       <function-signature>java.lang.String writeHello(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
   </function>   
</taglib>
```

With the following java code :

```
package your.package;

public class YourClass {

    public static String writeHello(String name) {
         return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

And in your JSP you can't do something like that :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="/WEB-INF/my-functions.tld" %>
...
${my:writeHello('toto')}
```

will render "Hello toto" on your page

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this [example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/calling-static-method-el) you will come to know what you are missing.